# "Unresolved attribute reference 'objects' for class 'Album' " in django using Pycharm

Tags: django-models, django-views

I follow bucky's tutorial for DJANGO and in my views file in line:
"all_albums = Album.objects.all()"  PYCHARM gives a warning: " Unresolved attribute reference 'objects' for class 'Album'" HERE IS MY CODE. Any help will be apreciated
AVRAAM AVRAMOPOULOS

## ----------------------------

```
from django.db import models


class Album(models.Model):
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=250,)
    album_title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    album_logo = models.CharField(max_length=1000)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.album_title) + "-" + str(self.artist)


class Song(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    file_type = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

### song_title = models.CharField(max_length=250)

### # my views file/

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

from .models import Album


def index(request):
    all_albums = Album.objects.all()
    html = ''
    for album in all_albums:
        path = '/music/' + str(album.id) + '/'
        html += '<a href="' + path + '">' + album.album_title + '</a><br/>'
    return HttpResponse(html)


def detail(request, album_id):
    return HttpResponse('<h2>Details for Album_id: ' + str(album_id) + '</h2>')
```

Comment: The code doesn't seem to have any fault. By "PyCharm gives an error", do you mean you're running the server (`python manage.py runserver`) via Pycharm?

Comment: Dear Nitin thank you for taking the time to answer.  This happens when I am editing  my "views"  file, Pycharm highlights the word "objects" and gives me this warning.  I am not running the server.

Answer (score 5):

Your code is fine and you'll be able to run it despite this warning from PyCharm. The warning is only on your PyCharm IDE, because Django specific PyCharm features aren't available. To get those you need the [professional edition](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html) of PyCharm and enable Django support here:

```
PyCharm / Preferences / Languages & Frameworks / Django
```

Comment: Dear Nitin everything is fine. thank you for your interest.

Comment: hi, if you use pycharm comm? pleas help me. how solved error?

Answer (score 1):

repost: in your Class definition, include a shortcut definition:

```
class MyPersistent(models.Model):
    objects = models.Manager()
```

Comment: is it true pycharm comm? need i pycharm prof?

Answer (score 0):

Just make command **pip install django-stubs**